# add uniform lbp to opencv (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I add below code [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/src/lbph_faces.cpp#L374)

```
static int uniform[256] = // for exactly 8 bits / neighbours !
{  
0,1,2,3,4,58,5,6,7,58,58,58,8,58,9,10,11,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,12,58,58,58,13,58,14,15,16,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,17,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,18,58,58,58,19,58,20,21,22,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,23,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,24,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,25,58,58,58,26,58,27,28,29,30,58,31,58,58,58,32,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,33,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,34,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,35,36,37,58,38,58,58,58,39,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,40,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,41,42,43,58,44,58,58,58,45,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,46,47,48,58,49,58,58,58,50,51,52,58,53,54,55,56,57};

Mat out;
Mat lookup(1,256,CV_32S, uniform); // make a Mat from it
LUT(lbp_image,lookup,lbp_image);
```

then also the number of histogram bins [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/src/lbph_faces.cpp#L377) from 256 to 59

but i got this error :

assertion failed : (lutcn == cn || lutcn == 1) && lut.total() == 256 && lut.isContinuous() && (src.depth() == CV_8U || src.depth() == CV_8S) in function LUT

i know that problem is in 
:
src.depth() == CV_8U || src.depth() == CV_8S)

please help me.

Comment: `static uchar uniform ...`, `Mat lookup(..., CV_8UC1, uniform)`, `lpb_image` should be of type `CV_8UC1`. However, I don't think that what you're doing makes any sense

Comment: why? im working on reduce memory size of  lbh xml ,and somewhere i read that uniform lbp is for reduce memory and wont affect on accuracy, so whats your means?    @Miki